# Making a picture enlarge on click. JavaScript, CSS and HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, image-enlarge

Found a guide here to make a picture enlarge by click but it´s not quite working. When I click to enlarge the image the small ones stay in front.

I put this in my html:

```
            <div class="bild1"><script type="text/javascript" src="funktions.js"></script>
            <img  src="bilder/3D.png" alt="Almanacka-projekt" style="cursor:pointer" onclick="showImage('bilder/3D_stor.png');">
            <div id="largeImgPanel" onclick="hideMe(this);">
            <img id="largeImg" style="height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0;">
           </div> 
        </div>

        <div class="bild2">
            <img  src="bilder/TopGame.png" alt="Almanacka-projekt" style="cursor:pointer" onclick="showImage('bilder/TopGame_stor.png');">
            <div id="largeImgPanel" onclick="hideMe(this);">
            <img id="largeImg" style="height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0;">
           </div>
        </div>

        <div class="bild3">
            <img  src="bilder/almanacka.png" alt="Almanacka-projekt" style="cursor:pointer" onclick="showImage('bilder/Almanacka_stor.png');">
            <div id="largeImgPanel" onclick="hideMe(this);">
            <img id="largeImg" style="height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0;">
            </div>
        </div>
```

css:

```
#largeImgPanel {
text-align: center;
visibility: hidden;
position: fixed;
z-index: 100;
top: 0; left: 0; 
width:100%;
height:100%; 
background-color: rgba(100,100,100, 0.5);}
```

javascript:

```
        function showImage(imgName) {
document.getElementById('largeImg').src = imgName;
showLargeImagePanel();
unselectAll();

}
function showLargeImagePanel() {
document.getElementById('largeImgPanel').style.visibility = 'visible';

}

function unselectAll() {
if(document.selection) document.selection.empty();
if(window.getSelection) window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();

}

function hideMe(obj) {
obj.style.visibility = 'hidden';}
```

Am I supposed to do it differently when I have multiple pictures?

Comment: Looks good http://jsfiddle.net/9qd1f1jd/. I guess some of your styles conflict.

Answer (score 1):

It looks great, you load pictures as demand! Maybe if you already used jQuery, you should add dynamic with fade in for instance http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue try this edit it worked for me

```
            <div class="bild1"><script type="text/javascript" src="funktions.js"></script>
        <img  src="bilder/3D.png" alt="Almanacka-projekt" style="cursor:pointer" onclick="showImage('bilder/3D_stor.png');">
    </div>

    <div class="bild2">
        <img  src="bilder/TopGame.png" alt="Almanacka-projekt" style="cursor:pointer" onclick="showImage('bilder/TopGame_stor.png');">
    </div>

    <div class="bild3">
        <img  src="bilder/almanacka.png" alt="Almanacka-projekt" style="cursor:pointer" onclick="showImage('bilder/Almanacka_stor.png');">
        <div id="largeImgPanel" onclick="hideMe(this);">
        <img id="largeImg" style="height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0;">
        </div>
    </div>
```